# Steps to use Entity Framework in WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have a question using Entity Framework in WCF. I am using .NET 4.5 with EF DbContext.

Here are the things I know to do to use EF in WCF. May be they are insufficient or some are not required.

1. Create EF ADO.NET Model.
2. Seperate the POCO classes to a seperate project (ProjectName: Entities) by using DbContext template generator.
3. Point the TT template of the POCO project to the edmx file in the data project (ProjectName: Data). "..\Data\MyEdmx.edmx"
4. Add [DataContract(IsReference(True))] and [DataMemeber] attributes in the .TT file of the POCO project so that the classes and properties will have the serialization attributes. Add Runtime.Serialization reference to the project and add the namespace to .TT file. This enables not to lose your attribute declaration while recreating the classes on a save of the .TT file or adding new entities.
5. Add ProjectName: Entities reference to Data project.
6. Turn off ProxyCreation and LazyLoading in the Context.tt file in the data project.
7. Add (ProjectName: Entities) and (ProjectName: Data) to your wcf service project.
8. Copy the EntityFramework connection string to your WCF project.
9. All your select methods in the service, must use .Include if you want the navigation objects to be populated. This gives better control when you want to load or or when you want limit data to show. Also, you don't get the child/related automatically due to lazyloading turned off.
10. Insert or Update or Delete, the service has to create the context and manually set the object state to be modified or added? Otherwise the changes will not be saved. Use the DbContext.Attach to attach and set the state of the entity appropriately Added,Modified, etc.

The problem I had was I could not find a good example of the steps to perform to use EF with WCF. I was able to see only bits and pieces. May be I am a late entrant to the WCF EF world hence could not find.

Not sure if I can use proxies WCF. I haven't understood completely the advantage of proxies yet.

I also read recommendations to use DTO as a layer between EF and the service. This requires a mapper to be in place. I don't know if I need it right away. But the idea is clear that it helps hide any unnecessary database columns showing in the business object. For example, audit columns such as created by, updated by etc we dont to show in the client.

I did not choose to use DataServices as I lose other binding options that I get from WCF. I don't know if it is a good thing to lose the simplicity of DataServices thinking about the future requirements of clients that require/support other binding mechanisms.

Any recommendations is appreciated.

**Additional Update**

I did find this in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457(v=vs.100).aspx. Some of the links were pointing to pre-release documentation. But this gives some more ideas for me in using EF and WCF.

This articles shows how to use proxies with WCF, change tracking of POCO. This is a good start for me. If any one has more advise please provide your thoughts.

**Update 2**
**Another Excellent Link for N-Tier**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882522.aspx

I am glad that the time I am spending is really educating me!

Comment: @Aron: Why? He writes explicitly that he "did **not** choose to use DataServices". I have added the WCF tag again.

Comment: My bad. Problem is that WCF being a SOAP tech is the wrong "shape" for CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

I progressed on using EF with WCF after lot of reading here and in other forums.

I followed the steps ahead. I was able to see the advantage of using DTO. This really allows you to hide fields that you don't need to expose to the client or other services. But I am holding back on introducing DTO due to time constraints.

I used context.Attach, context.Add and context.Entry.

I also did a small prototype to use WCF Data Service. That was very fast paced development. I am holding back on using WCF data services for now due to time constraint in learning its features.